# Wildcard Characters in count()

Tags: python, string, list, count

Is there any way we can use wildcard characters in `count()` ?

Lets say I have a list:

```
lst = ["abXY", "cdXY", "efXY", "ghVW", "ijVW"]
```

Here, I want to count the occurrences of items ending with "XY".

Is there any in-built `count()` like method to this?

This won't work:

```
lst.count("%XY")
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you can use `str.endswith`:

```
>>> lst = ["abXY", "cdXY", "efXY", "ghVW", "ijVW"]
>>> sum(1 for x in lst if x.endswith("XY"))
3
```

For more general "wildcard" matching, use a regular expression.

```
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile(".*XY$")
>>> sum(1 for x in lst if p.match(x))
3
```

You *could* also use `lst.count` by defining a special class that uses regex-matching in its `__eq__` method, but I really don't see why you'd want to do that...

```
class M:
    def __init__(self, p):
        self.p = "^" + p.replace("%", ".*") + "$"
    def __eq__(self, x):
        return re.match(p, x)

>>> lst.count(M("%XY"))
3
```

Comment: This would be ideal for most cases, but what if you are working  with thousands of values? You'd be wasting recources looping through each element.

Comment: @Countour-Integral Well, if you want to check all values, you have to loop through all values, right? `count` does the same thing, just without a visible `for` keyword.

Comment: for an array of lenght 5 iterating is the way to go , but looping is not the only way to do this, for example in C# `.count()` uses O(1) operations for this and other similar  array manipulation methods. this also is the same in Python when working with querysets in `Django`. You do not loop through each row in the database if you only want to find a specific pattern.